# Does “tripping” on psychedelics come from “tryptamine”?

Tags: etymology

Is there a good resource on this? I found nothing authoritative on the internet.

Comment: What makes you think there's a link?

Comment: The term trip was first coined by US Army scientists during the 1950s when they were experimenting with LSD. - Lee, Martin A. (1985). Acid Dreams: The Complete Social History of LSD.

Comment: @Gio that's what [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychedelic_experience#Etymology) claims, with a reference to a book which does not show it on the displayed page. I would think it is far more likely that the colloquialism came from those (non-army) people who previously took it, as a synonym for a *journey* or *excursion*.

Comment: @WeatherVane - the sense of a journey is its most likely origin, whoever said it first. Nothing to do with tryptamine, anyway.

Comment: @Gio agreed on that.

Comment: This is where the question comes from : “*No reputable etymological source online speaks about this subject. I've heard that it comes from "trip" as in "journey, voyage," which makes sense because that's how it is usually translated into other languages. However, I've also heard reports that it's a shortening of DMT's full name, dimethyltryptamine.*” Reddit

Comment: @Gio it can't be from the Army's experiments in LSD because *lysergic acid diethylamide* is not **tryp...**